# How to hide winrar or other apk files in general?

Tags: applications, security, apk, hidden

I have stored some important files in my android phone in rar format. I've hidden these files in .nomedea folder. I've also enabled password for these files via win rar. The problem is for opening these files I need a rar explorer app. But my friend always delete this app. I tried hiding the app with other apps like applocker but the problem is when my friend uses shareit he can see all the apps. I don't want the rar app to get discovered because knowing the presence of suspicious apps can let my friend know about the importatn hidden files and he'll fist off delete all the suspicious apps. I tried to put the winrar apk file in .nomedea folder, thinking I'd install it every time I need it and uninstall it, but it shows up in file explorer's APK folder.

Another problem is that when we switch on the hidden files mode of the file explorer and simply search`.` all the hidden files are shown. And the worst happens if we search `.apk`, `.rar` or `.dil` or other extensions, the most important files show up easily on the top.

So the question is,

> How do I hide the WinRar apk file in my android phone such that no one else can in any way find it.

P.S: I can't root the phone yet because it will invalidate the guarantee period.

Comment: I'm confused about your relationship with your friend, why they are freely messing with your phone... and about your suspicious apps... and WinRAR APK file (did you put an APK inside a RAR file?). The simplest is to rename the extension to something uncommon, like `.xyz` or anything you want.

Comment: @AndrewT. My friend has some mental problem. I didn't put the apk file in rar. I archived some video and audio files via Winrar and set password to them. My friend was deleting some of my songs which he doesn't like so I found the most geeky way to hide them from him. But still this method require Winrar which he deletes too.

Comment: Probably the simplest workaround is to rename the extension of the RAR file to e.g. `.xyz`, or `.exe`, or even `.txt` (but you need to rename the file back to open it)

Comment: This is what I have done recently. I renamed the Winrar to xyz.dll. I actually gave it such a name that it seems to be operating system's important file. Renaming the RAR file won't work because I still would have to extract it with winrar. Instead changing the extension winrar.apk itself solved the whole issue.

Comment: In the first comment it is  _"...I found the most **geeky** way to..."_

Comment: Disable your default file manager, install ES File Explorer or MiXplorer file manager app. Both of them can create an archive in ZIP, 7z and TAR format and supports encryption as well. Both of them can also hide the file inside them, so search feature of those apps wouldn't list any of the hidden files.

Comment: Which Android version and device is it? Does the device not support creation of a secondary user? Why not create a separate profile/user for your friend?

Comment: @Firelord I am using Yu yuphoria android lollipop. It has a default file explorer. I didn't know that separate user profiles can be created in android.

Comment: See http://www.greenbot.com/article/2949981/android/how-to-add-change-or-delete-users-in-android-lollipop.html